# How do I set up CloudLab for a Simple Experiment?

Tags: cloud, gpu, cpu, lossless-compression

I am trying to test compression/decompression algorithms on GPU and CPU machines. I am very new to CloudLab and I have almost 0 idea of how to set it up and use it. I was hoping to get some help on how I can go about setting up machines for my experiment. I need a simple CPU machine and a simple GPU machine that's all. Can someone help with this? What specification should the profile have? This is what the Topology editor of a profile looks like. What kind of node should I add? Thank you in advance. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if there's any information that I could give. [image]